# How can I modify the default description when using org-insert-link with custom IDs in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I use `CUSTOM_ID` in my documents for internal links.

To copy a link, I use `org-store-link` (`C-c l`) and then `org-insert-link` (`C-c C-l`) to insert the link elsewhere.

However, `org-insert-link` does not prompt for a description as it normally does, but inserts its own of the form:

```
[[#custom-id-1234][file:~/org/my-file.org::#custom-id-1234]]
```

This is not what I want. That description is irrelevant to me. I do not need to know the file name. It would be better to use the headline title as the description, or to be prompted for one.

I can edit the description using `org-insert-link` (`C-c C-l`) again over the link, but this is an extra step I would like not to do.

This behavior is caused by `org-store-link` (I think), which adds this link into `org-stored-links` with this description. However, I have not found how to change the way these links are inserted.

Is there a way to change this default behavior?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you are describing: `C-c C-l` offers me two links to choose from, a custom id link and a headline link. When I choose the custom id link, I get asked for a description which I type in. The resulting link looks like this: `[[#custom-id-1234][two]]` where `two` is what I typed into the description prompt.

Comment: You are probably on version 9.5.5, correct? There seems to be a fix for this in version 9.6, so you might want to upgrade.

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior you are describing in Org mode version 9.5.5. The fix is in [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=c3d6672cfdbff8c9dd4c2ec70886ad3f62153d07).

Comment: Thanks a lot NickD. I was running version 9.5.2. An upgrade solved the problem.